# Error message: Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Tags: php, heroku

I tried to post images on Heroku.
but images can't be generated and wasn't displayed on Heroku.
images are displayed on localhost when I post.

An article told me that it can be display with base64.
please help.

#### PostsController

```
    public function store(PostRequest $request)
    {
        $image_file = "";
        $upload_image = $request->file('image_file');
        $post->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->image->getRealPath())); //here is error
        if ($upload_image) {
            $path = $upload_image->store('uploads', 'public');
            if ($path) {
                Image::make($upload_image->getRealPath())->resize(150, 150)->save();
                $image_file = $path;
            }
        }

        $post  = new Post;
        $post->subject = $request->subject;
        $post->message = $request->message;
        $post->image_file = $image_file;
        $post->name = "";
        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/bbs')->with('poststatus', '');
    }
```

#### index.blade

```php
               <td>
                    @if (empty($post->image_file))
                    
                    @else
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?= $post->image ?>" width="150px"> 
                    @endif
                </td>
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `$request->image` to contain? Shouldn't it be `$upload_image->getRealPath()` (but located inside the if-statement so you know it exists)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean that you "need" base64. Normally you upload an image, store it in some folder, store the filename in the database and just output the link to the image in the src.

Comment: I"d like to post images and display on heroku. it wasn't show up error message before I adding this code"$post->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->image->getRealPath()));" 

also, there was displayed on localhost. but didn't on heroku